# Styling cms static block in luma theme - Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, javascript, css

I had created a couple of **cms static blocks** in Magento 2 **luma** theme and added `inline styles` and `javascript` inside the blocks. Now I'm confused that where I could place those **CSS** and **js** files inside the directory and how to call it.

Answer (score 3):

For styling your CMS Blocks add custom CSS, js or adding bootstrap, call files in default_head_blocks.xml

```
#app/design/frontend/yourvendor/yourtheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml


<css src="css/bootstrap.css" />
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Place both files under `/app/design/frontend/yourvendor/yourtheme/web/css` or js

***you can call all required CSS and js files in same way***

Comment: I couldnt see any files inside app/design/frontend.

Comment: you should have extended your theme

Comment: I tried to add the custom css file inside vendor\magento\theme-frontend-luma\Magento_Theme\web\css ,And called css files inside  vendor\magento\theme-frontend-luma\Magento_Theme\layout\default_head_blocks.xml.But css is not lodaing.

Comment: I found that ,we had to paste the css files inside pub/static frontend/Magento/luma/css and this worked for me.

Comment: Bad idea @ren - That directory will be deleted when you run a static-content deploy and you'll lose your changes.

Comment: this will be gone once you clear the cache and deploy static content this is not the right place to add your custom css , you need to extend your  theme

Comment: yes u r right manoj.Can u tell me how to extend the magento luma theme.

Comment: This is described in previous question : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91930/how-to-extend-the-luma-theme

Comment: According to magento front end developer guide icreated a new theme and configured it in backend.Now im confused about default_head_blocks.xml.I already  pasted Magento_Theme folder from magento luma theme from vendor and passed css link in default_head_blocks.xml,unfortunately css file is not loding.