# Make custom theme in magento

Tags: magento2, module, admin, xml

I am designing a store and finding it hard to customize a theme. I have worked on html only but not on xml so please ignore my mistakes.

Is it good to make your `own-theme` or should i stick with the `pre-installed` theme and change/modify it?

Second, If I design a theme i have to design all the backend also? or magento automatically linked it with the `admin-panel`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do some home-work for this first as you have lot of doubts regarding magento2 and its theme development.

You can check magento documentaion for complete details and link provided by @price in comment.

You are beginner do here are few things you which answer you questions and you can proceed further:

1. You can create new theme from extending LUMA theme. [Follow this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/92159/29175)
2. No need to do anything in ADMIN for designing/developing front-end theme. In admin you only need to activate your `developed-theme`. You can do by simply going to `ADMIN-> Content-> Design -> Configuration -> Edit`. [Documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-apply.html) for more details.

Explaining more about `create new theme`: You can create new theme by following above provided link and only copy files which you need to change/modify.   This is best practice for you at this level and this is how most of theme get developed by extending LUMA or BLANK. You should start with extending LUMA as mention in [post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/92159/29175).

Good luck.

Comment: yeah i have doubts because i really dont know what is good approach in this.  .

Comment: Please follow the answer and links mentioned in it. You will have good start. Just complete first step.

Comment: Thank you for your comment really helpful. Just some things i want to ask is it necessary to extend luma theme. If i am starting from scratch so why not own theme desigining everything? second thing i was having hard time in changing the header color in luma theme and still not able to find this.

Comment: Yes, you should extend LUMA. (Best for you at this level). and for changing header color, you can post another question. We never edit core files so first to extend that.

Comment: actually i am not asking how to change sorry for unclear comment. I want to ask will it be the same as changing colors in the luma ?

Comment: Yes, it will be same. Not even color but almost everything.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [official document](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html) to create a new storefront theme.
You don't need to create admin theme until you want to make any changes in the admin panel design.

Comment: Is it easy to make a new theme or should i have stick to the current theme and change the theme ?

Comment: It's easy and referred to create custom theme rather make changes in core theme.

Comment: This theme will automatically be linked to my backend? i mean having widgets will be easy?

Comment: follow the steps from the link and the theme will work perfectly as you want

Answer (score -2):

The best way to create your custom theme is to copy all files from Magento's Luma theme into your Design folder and then make changes you want. Also it is not an easy job to make frontend on Magento. So be brave :)

Comment: thank you for you motivational comment Obscuro :). So it is a good option to change the current luma theme according to my needs? Like i want to change the font i want to change the colors of the headers.

Comment: not exactly, you need to go to vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma and get all files from there to your (app/design/... ) theme folder (google how to make your own M2 theme) and only then you can modify your files. First rule of magento developers - "do not modify core files".

Comment: I would advice against copying all the files, it makes updates more difficult and provides much more code to maintain. Personally I prefer the method of only overriding what you need.

Comment: i think its better to make a new custom theme.