# Not able to extend Luma theme

Tags: frontend, custom-attributes, magento2.3.1

I needed to add an attribute brand to Luma theme. For this, I will have to create a new theme. I created one by extending Luma theme. I followed all the steps to extend Luma theme as described here [How to extend the Luma Theme?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91930/how-to-extend-the-luma-theme). However, I am still not seeing the content of Luma theme. It looks like the Magento blank theme. I have followed every step adding theme.xml, reistration.php, composer.json, the etc, media,i18n & web folders & also have checked the theme table in database. I am not sure what am I missing here.
I theme folder is at app/design/frontend/Mycompany/Mytheme with capital  Ms in the folder names.However,  when I used capital letters in theme.xml, it gave me an error. I switched back to small letters there was no error , however there's no content of luma theme either. 
Can anyone please point to the error?
Regards,
Sujatha

Comment: 1) you media folder add `preview.jpg` file ??? 2) after you run all command ???

Comment: Yes. I had done that. But i realised that the widgets were all attched to LUMA theme. After I created a new home page widget for my new theme, I could see the homepage content. But, now I see that my category pages are not showing up properly. Need to work on the same. May be on the same lines.